# White space not removing when using firefox with clipbord js

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard.js

I am using clipbord.js When I click on my button and copy the code and then paste it some where it leaves quite a large gap at the top

I have tried using `.replace(/\s/g, "")` on here

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/rrxEyQ) ***--> Link has been updated with working code***

> Question: When use firefox how to make sure that there is no gap when I have copied the code and then go to paste it.
>
> There is no gap when I use **Google Chrome**, **Edge**, **Internet Explore**

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    new Clipboard("#copy-button", {
        text: function(trigger) {
            var str = $(trigger).parent().find('pre').text();
            return str.replace(/\s/g, "");
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="page-header"><h1>Clean URLs</h1></div>  
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">
<h1 class="panel-title">Example 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
<button type="button" id="copy-button" data-clipboard-target="#h1" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Copy</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
<pre id="h1">
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</pre>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">
<h1 class="panel-title">Example 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
<button type="button" id="copy-button" data-clipboard-target="#h2" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Copy</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
<pre id="h2">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /root_folder_name/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</pre>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>


</div>
```

Comment: I have tested your pen, but everything seems fine for me (chrome)

Comment: @TobiasTimm when I paste copied code into edit it shows lots of spaces at top of copied code

Comment: i've tried it with every field and every combination. I don't have any leading whitespaces at all. Hm which browser are you using?

Comment: @TobiasTimm firefox latest version working in chrome but not firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `$(trigger).parent().find('pre').text()` returned empty string. So, I've modified it to `$(trigger).closest('.panel').find('pre').text();`

Check the pen http://codepen.io/pranesh-r/pen/QKEjEr